# React not rendering component with inline styling on IOS

Tags: reactjs, state

I ran into a problem with my component not re-rendering after a state change, when using props driven inline styling, on IOS/iphone (not tested on ipad).

Here is the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-meitner-2sju9?file=/src/FlexboxGap.jsx

Edit: adding the code here too as requested:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./FlexboxGap.styles.css";

function FlexboxGap({ visible, containerCat, propertiesCat }) {
  const [gap, setGap] = useState(0);
  const [rowGap, setRowGap] = useState(0);
  const [columnGap, setColumnGap] = useState(0);

  function onGapChange(event) {
    setGap(event.target.value);
    setRowGap(event.target.value);
    setColumnGap(event.target.value);
  }
  function onRowChange(event) {
    setRowGap(event.target.value);
  }
  function onColumnChange(event) {
    setColumnGap(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="main-container">
      <div>
        {" "}
        <div>gap: {gap}px</div>
        <input
          type="range"
          className="slider-bar"
          min={0}
          max={20}
          value={gap}
          onChange={onGapChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        {" "}
        <div>row-gap: {rowGap}px</div>
        <input
          type="range"
          className="slider-bar"
          min={0}
          max={20}
          value={rowGap}
          onChange={onRowChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        {" "}
        <div>column-gap: {columnGap}px</div>
        <input
          type="range"
          className="slider-bar"
          min={0}
          max={20}
          value={columnGap}
          onChange={onColumnChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          width: "100vw",
          height: "250px",
          backgroundColor: "grey",
          display: "flex",
          flexFlow: "row wrap",
          justifyContent: "flex-start",
          alignContent: "flex-start",
          rowGap: `${rowGap}px`,
          columnGap: `${columnGap}px`
        }}
      >
        <div className="graph-item">item</div>
        <div className="graph-item">item</div>
        <div className="graph-item">item</div>
        <div className="graph-item">item</div>
        <div className="graph-item">item</div>
        <div className="graph-item">item</div>
        <div className="graph-item">item</div>
        <div className="graph-item">item</div>
        <div className="graph-item">item</div>
        <div className="graph-item">item</div>
        {/* This last invisible div is a hack to "force" react to re-render, by referencing the props rowGap and columnGap. 
        Otherwise, the rerender fails to happen on iphones. Working on Android
        and desktop */}
        <div className="hack-ghost">{`${rowGap}${columnGap}`}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FlexboxGap;
```

While the state of rowGap and rowColumn is successfully changed, as well as the style, the div that depends on it does not get updated **on iphones** (fully updated).
Works on desktop and android devices.

I found a hack by adding a div that references the 2 states I need, and everything now "works".

The problem is:

1- it is hacky and

2-i am not sure i fully understand what is going on.

I thought of this hack by thinking that "i needed react to notice that the state changed inside this element".

Is it an issue with the way that inline css works // an ios implementation particularity?

Kind regards.

Comment: Please post code here directly. Also, how do you know that react state is not updating? How are you checking this? Are you aware that `setState()` is asyncronous?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I see the state being updated on the <div>column-gap: {columnGap}px</div>, but not on the div that contains the state driven inline styling.

Comment: And how are you viewing this state? And what do you mean by "the div that contains the state driven inline styling"? Does that div have an `id` so we can refer to it more explicitly?

Comment: "This last invisible div is a hack to force react to update the state" This sounds like you found a hack to force react to **render** the component. This is different than "update the state". Maybe this correction in terminology will help in your googling to find a better solution.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice How am i viewing this state change? I see that when i move my sliders, the values are correctly updated in my devtools. Thanks for the help with pointing at the right terminology. I see now that what i meant was that the state is updated correctly, but that the component whose inline styles are state driven are not rendered even though an update occured.

Comment: From your original question, I was thinking you were asking about the state updating. Glad we cleared that up. If you haven't already, I suggest installing the React devtools (it's unclear which devtools you are referring to in your previous comment).

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me clarifying the issue! I can now search a little more efficiently. I have the chrome react devtools to help, if it is what you referred to :).